# unable to switch to console/terminal from login screen ubunt 22,04

Tags: command-line, login

On the login screen if I do CTRL ALT F3 or similar I get a blank screen and my monitor goes into power saving.

I am able to login and switch to GUI using F7.

Any ideas.

Comment: try ctrl+alt+f2

Comment: You might have to hit the `Enter` key on a "blank" screen, in order to wake up the `getty`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get to the tty. It is frozen and no prompt.